# img and iframes

Tags: html

here is my code snippet

```
<img src="images/home.jpg" height="40" width="150" />
<img src="images/contact.jpg" height="40" width="150" />
```

and

```
<iframe src="aboutseels.php" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="360" ></iframe>
```

now, i was wondering if there is a way that when the client clicks one of the images, the src of the iframe will change??

for example if i click on the second image the src of the iframe will be src="contactus.php"

Comment: it's possible if you use jquery or javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set a `name` attribute on the `iframe` and wrap the images in an `a` tag with the `target` attribute to be the same name.

```
<iframe name="foo" ...></iframe>
<a href="newlink" target="foo">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the javascript library [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and then use the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to capture clicks on the images it could look something like this

```
$(function(){
 $('img').click(function(){
   iframeSrc = this.attr('title');
   $('iframe').attr('src',iframeSrc);
});
});
```

and the html could look like this then

```
  <img src="images/home.jpg" height="40" width="150" title="http://google.com" />
    <img src="images/contact.jpg" height="40" width="150" title="http://facebook.com"/>
    <iframe src="aboutseels.php" id="iframe" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="360" ></iframe>
```

Or use regular html and use target

```
<a target="iframe" href="http://facebook.com"><img src="images/home.jpg" height="40" width="150" title="http://google.com" /></a>
<a target="iframe" href="http://google.com"><img src="images/contact.jpg" height="40" width="150" title="http://facebook.com"/></a>
<iframe src="aboutseels.php" id="iframe" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="360" ></iframe>
```

Comment: why mix in jquery when browsers do this automatically?

Comment: dunno what happened but shit got dirty... when i was typing, just wanted to show alternatives, and went ahead to post the first block to be first...